# Syntax error when trying to run debug configuration for remote interpretor from PyCharm

Tags: django, google-app-engine, vagrant, pycharm

I'm setting up a Google App Engine Django project to run in a Vagrant environment for easy setup/teardown of the system and am using PyCharm as the IDE for it all. I'm able to successfully get the server to run using PyCharm on the remote machine, but if I try to use the remote debugger to start a debug session, PyCharm gives me a nondescript error:

```
Error running webapp: Can't run remote python interpreter: Couldn't obtain remote socket from output , stderr   File "", line 1
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'll try to include as much info about the setup as I can:

- Windows 10 host machine, Ubuntu 14.04 guest
- Python is version 2.7.10
- `/home/vagrant/www/shell/python-su.sh` setup as python interpreter. Just passing arguments to `sudo /usr/bin/python $@` to make it work in vagrant/GAE
- GAE Directory in PyCharm is set to `/home/vagrant/google_appengine/` to make it work on the remote machine
- Here's a screenshot of my PyCharm Configuration Settings for launching debug client: 
  [image: PyCharm Configuration Settings]

All of this matches what I do for the run configuration and that works fine. It's only the debug configuration throwing this error.

Comment: What is the full command shown in the debugging console when you first hit debug? That may give you a hint as to what isn't working correctly.

Comment: When I hit Debug, the console opens and shows what command it is running. Do you see something like this http://snag.gy/nHzCc.jpg

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Debug is greyed out for me and I can show that window (maybe because it can't debug?) But the Python console does show a bit more, I'll update with that info

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Ah, nevermind, looks like that might have been unrelated. It looks like the console isn't picking up the python path for some reason, so it's complaining about not finding django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the help documentation for PyCharm, I found [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827557-Enabling-SSH-FTP-debug-logging-to-report-problems-with-deployment-and-remote-SDK-configuration) detailing how to turn on more logging to the PyCharm log file. Add this to the log.xml file located in the /bin/ directory of the PyCharm Program Files directory:

```
<category name="#com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
```

Looking at the log file showed what command it was trying to run, which I was able to run by SSH-ing into the machine to run it myself. From there, I was able to figure it it was coming from my sudo python file. I had to wrap the `$@` in quotes to get it to work properly. The run was working because the arguments were simple enough that it didn't matter that it wasn't quoted. The final python sudo shell file looks like this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python "$@"
```

Comment: this helped. I had the same problem when wrapping the python interpreter in an centos scl environment. The right invocation is:    source scl_source enable rh-python34 && python "$@"

Comment: I'm running a custom python launcher script to set up the environment.  Adding quotes around the arguments (`"$@"`) solved it for me!